# How to generate CSV file in cakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, csv, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am beginner in cakePHP and woking on cakePHP 2.0. I am trying to generate CSV file, to accomplish this task i am using the following method.

[cake php official site refr.](https://bakery.cakephp.org/2013/06/23/CakePHP-2-Export-as-CSV-plugin.html)

[github refr.](https://github.com/joshuapaling/CakePHP-Export-CSV-Plugin)

i have got stucked in step no. 2 when it is loading the plugin. the following error is occurring in app/Config/bootstrap.php file

> Fatal error: Class 'CakePlugin' not found in /var/www/html/sitefolder/app/config/bootstrap.php on line 51

```
CakePlugin::load('Export');
```

Please correct me.
Thnaks

Comment: This is maybe due to bad Cakephp installation, Try to reinstall it and make sure you are using the latest version 2.x

Comment: I'd recommend using [CsvView](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview/tree/cake2) for exporting to CSV in Cake.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja not working. same error is displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thnaks guys for your precious response on this

For now i have find the solution of this by following steps.

1. download the plugin files form
   https://github.com/joshuapaling/CakePHP-Export-CSV-Plugin
2. by pass the step no.2 and step no.3 of what they have mentioned in [official refer.](https://github.com/joshuapaling/CakePHP-Export-CSV-Plugin)
3. copy the file "ExportComponent.php" from plugin and paste it in

   > site_folder/app/controllers/components
4. add it in controller's component array variable

   `$components = array('blabla1', 'blabal2', 'Export')`
5. create $data array variable (which contains the csv file data ) and just do like

   `$this->Export->exportCsv($data, 'filename1.csv');`

Its done and working fine for me